# centered position: fixed on mobile browser zooms incorrectly

Tags: html, css

I've got a logo on top of a page which has to be centered relative to the text and fixed to the top of the viewport like in this example: http://dev.markbrouwers.nl/test.html

```
<h1 style="width: 200px; height: 100px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <img src="images/logoforeground.png" style="position: fixed; display: block;" alt="Page title">
</h1>
<div style="width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <p>content</p>
</div>
```

It works perfectly on pc's. Yet on mobile browsers when zooming the logo starts drifting away from the center. 
I've read quite some things (e.g. [this](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/new-mobile-safari-stuff-in-ios5-position-fixed-overflow-scroll-new-input-type-support-web-workers-ecmascript-5)) about position fixed on iOS and apparently as of iOS 5 and Android 2.2 it should work, thought it doesn't... it still drifts... Does anyone know how to make mobile webkit behave like the pc browsers?

[edit]

I edited the html a bit, h1 is now outside the container

I also made a screenshot on an iPhone and Windows. As you can see the logo drifts off the viewport when you zoom in on iOS. In chrome browser it stays in the top middle of the viewport.

**Safari/iOS5 screenshot:**
[image]

**Chrome/Win7 screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: I've tested it on my android 2.3.6 nexus one, and for me it's normal behaviour, your logo keeps being centered on the page, but when you're zooming, the page tends to scroll to right following the motion of your fingers. But after zooming, you can move the horizontal scrollbar to the center and your logo will be there at the center of the page too.

Answer (score 0):

The Reason this happens, is mobile devices need to know the width of the page, even if the width of your page is 340px for e.g you will still run into this issue, it is because your ZOOMING, not resizing.

If you want text to be larger of the user, the best solution is have something like the following:

Two buttons Small / Large

then link those buttons to some javascript that then changes the text size based on what you want.

for e.g. when click large you might want it to go to 24px
and when they click small it goes to 14px.

It is simple javascript